# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '# NRECS: 1096\n'

Tags: python, linux, arcgis, netcdf

I am kinda new to Python, and would really appreciate some help with the following code. The purpose is to take individual variable data from the respective column from each of the (258) files and convert them into a single NetCDF4 file. These NetCDF files will then be imported into ArcGIS and converted to raster format. Part of the output file is as follows:

```
    # NRECS: 1096
# DT: 24
# STARTDATE: 1999-01-01 00:00:00
# ALMA_OUTPUT: 0
# NVARS: 10
# YEAR  MONTH   DAY OUT_SNOW_COVER   OUT_SURF_TEMP   OUT_RUNOFF  OUT_BASEFLOW    OUT_SWE     OUT_EVAP    OUT_PREC
1999    01  01  0.0000   -0.6910     0.0000  1.7175  0.0000  1.2187  1.2250
1999    01  02  0.0000   -8.1983     0.0000  1.7042  0.0000  0.0132  0.0000
1999    01  03  0.0000   -13.7701    0.0000  1.6907  0.0000  0.0076  0.0000
1999    01  04  1.0000   -11.0906    0.0000  1.6772  6.1095  0.4404  7.4750
1999    01  05  1.0000   -7.4365     0.0000  1.6637  9.7234  0.6585  4.3000
1999    01  06  1.0000   -6.4047     0.0000  1.6501  12.1842     0.5672  3.0000
1999    01  07  1.0000   -9.1578     0.0000  1.6364  12.0282     0.5211  0.0000
```

The code is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

#----------------------------------------------------
# Program to convert VIC fluxes files to NetCDF file
# will ask the user which variable he wants to export
# and also for which years. Assumes there is data
# for the entire time period, from 1-jan to 31-dec
# SET UP FOR DAILY TIME STEP. FLUX FILE SHOUD NOT
# CONTAIN HOUR RECORD!!
#----------------------------------------------------

#------------------------------------------------
# Writen by Daniel de Castro Victoria
# dvictori@cena.usp.br or daniel.victoria@gmail.com
# Needs python libraries Numeric and Scientific
# 03-dec-2004
#
# Script updated by Kel Markert
# kel.markert@nasa.gov or kel.markert@uah.edu
#-------------------------------------------------

# import dependencies
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os, string
# handle dates...
import datetime as dt
# NetCDF and Numeric
from netCDF4 import *
from numpy import *

def flux2nc(influxes,outpath,var=None,start_year=None,end_year=None):

    # building file list and sorted lat lon list
    dirin = os.path.dirname(influxes)

    try:
        file_list = os.listdir(dirin)
    except OSError:
        raise OSError('Input flux directory not valid, please fix path')

    lat_t = []
    lon_t = []
    lat = []
    lon = []

    try:
        for f in file_list:
            lat_t.append(float(str.split(f, "_")[1]))
            lon_t.append(float(str.split(f, "_")[2]))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Input path contains files that are not flux files')

    for i in lat_t:
        if i not in lat:
            lat.append(i)

    for i in lon_t:
        if i not in lon:
            lon.append(i)


    # putting in order. Lat should be from top to botom
    # lon from left to right
    lon.sort()
    lat.sort()
    lat.reverse()

    del(lat_t)
    del(lon_t)

    # if variable is not set, get it from user
    if var == None:

        #determining the parameter to use
        print("Choose output parameter")
        print("1 - SNOW_COVER")
        print("2 - SURFACE_TEMPERATURE")
        print("3 - Runoff")
        print("4 - Base flow")
        print("5 - Snow Water Equivalent")
        print("6 - EVAPORATION")
        print("7 - PRECIPITATION")
        varini = input('Choose output (1 a 7)>')

        #getting the column right
        if int (varini) < 7:
            var = varini + 2
        elif varini == 6:        #more than one soil layer...
            camada = input('which soil layer?>')
            var = varini + 2 + camada

    #set name of out_file. Named after parameter choice
    if var == 3:
        var_txt = "ppt"
        var_name = "Precipitation"
    elif var == 4:
        var_txt = "evap"
        var_name = "Evapotranspiration"
    elif var == 5:
        var_txt = "runoff"
        var_name = "Runoff"
    elif var == 6:
        var_txt = "base"
        var_name = "Baseflow"
    elif var == 7:
        var_txt = "swe"
        var_name = "Snow Water Equivalent"
    else:
        var_txt = "soilLyr"+str(camada)
        var_name = "Soil moisture, layer {0}".format(camada)

    # if the date information is not set get it from user
    if start_year == None:
        # for what date?
        start_year = input("Enter start year:")
    if end_year == None:
        end_year = input("End year:")

    # set date information in datetime object
    inidate = dt.date(start_year,1,1)
    enddate = dt.date(end_year,12,31)

    # calculate number of days in time series
    days = enddate.toordinal() - inidate.toordinal()+1

    #print "Gridding {0} data...".format(var_name)

    #
    # create array containig all data
    # This is going to be huge. Create an array with -9999 (NoData)
    # Then populate the array by reading each flux file
    #

    all_data = zeros([days,len(lat),len(lon)], dtype=float32)
    all_data[:,:,:] = -9999

    c = len(file_list)

    # for each file in list
    for f in file_list:
        # get lat & lon and it's index
        latitude = float(str.split(f, sep="_")[1])
        longitude = float(str.split(f, sep="_")[2])
        lat_id = lat.index(latitude)
        lon_id = lon.index(longitude)

        c = c -1

        infile = open(dirin+'/'+f, "r")
        lixo = infile.readlines()
        infile.close()
        dado = []

        for l in lixo:
            if int(string.split(l, sep="\t")[0]) in range(inidate.year, enddate.year+1):
                dado.append(float(str.split(l, sep="\t")[var]))
            # putting data inside array.
            # Since data has lat & lon fixed uses dimension [:,lat_index,lon_index]

        all_data[:,lat_id,lon_id] = dado

    del dado # del data to free memory for large datasets

    try:

        # open netCDF file for writing
        ncfile = Dataset(outpath+str(var_txt)+'_'+str(start_year)+".nc", "w")

        # set netCDF metadata information
        ncfile.Conventions = "CF-1.6"
        ncfile.title = "VIC hydrologic flux outputs"
        ncfile.source = 'VIC hydrologic model 4.2.d'
        ncfile.history = "Created using the script created by NASA SERVIR. " + dt.date.today().isoformat()
        ncfile.date_created = str(dt.datetime.now())
        ncfile.references = "N/A"
        ncfile.comment = "N/A"

        ncfile.start_date = inidate.isoformat()
        ncfile.end_date = enddate.isoformat()

        #create dimensions
        ncfile.createDimension("longitude", len(lon))
        ncfile.createDimension("latitude", len(lat))
        ncfile.createDimension("time", days)

        #create variables
        latvar = ncfile.createVariable("latitude", float, ("latitude",))
        latvar.long_name = "Latitude"
        latvar.units = "degrees_north"
        latvar[:] = lat

        lonvar = ncfile.createVariable("longitude", float, ("longitude",))
        lonvar.long_name = "Longitude"
        lonvar.units = "degrees_east"
        lonvar[:] = lon

        timevar = ncfile.createVariable("time", int, ("time",))
        timevar.long_name = "Time"
        timevar.units = "days since " + inidate.isoformat()
        timevar.calendar = 'gregorian'
        timevar[:] = range(0, days)

        # save gridded flux data to file
        data_var = ncfile.createVariable(var_txt, float, ("time","latitude","longitude"))
        data_var.long_name = var_name
        data_var.missing_value = -9999.0
        data_var.units = "mm"
        data_var[:] = all_data[:,:,:]

        # close the file
        ncfile.close()

    except IOError:
        raise IOError('Output path is not valid, please fix the path string')

    return

def main():
    # checking user input
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Wrong user input")
        print("Convert VIC fluxes files to NetCDF")
        print("usage flux2cdf.py <vic flux dir> <out netcdf dir>")
        print("DIR INPUTS SHOULD CONTAIN TRAILING /")
        sys.exit()

    if sys.argv[1][-1] != "/":
        print("VIC FLUX DIR SHOULD CONTAIN TRAILING /")
        print("fixing it for you...")
        sys.argv[1] = sys.argv[1] + "/"

    print("IMPORTANT: "+sys.argv[1]+" SHOULD CONTAIN ONLY FLUXES FILES!!!")

    flux2nc(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])

    return

# Execute the main level program if run as standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```
    python3 flux2nc_a.py /mnt/d/Spring_2020/VIC/VIC_Output/ /mnt/d/Spring_2020/VIC/VIC_Output/NetCDF
IMPORTANT: /mnt/d/Spring_2020/VIC/VIC_Output/ SHOULD CONTAIN ONLY FLUXES FILES!!!
Choose output parameter
1 - SNOW_COVER
2 - SURFACE_TEMPERATURE
3 - Runoff
4 - Base flow
5 - Snow Water Equivalent
6 - EVAPORATION
7 - PRECIPITATION
Choose output (1 a 7)>1
Enter start year:1999
End year:2000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flux2nc_a.py", line 241, in <module>
    main()
  File "flux2nc_a.py", line 235, in main
    flux2nc(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
  File "flux2nc_a.py", line 156, in flux2nc
    if int(str.split(l, sep="\t")[0]) in range(inidate.year, enddate.year+1):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '# NRECS: 1096\n'
```

Update 1:
After fixing the header error thanks to Massimo, I am now getting the error:

```
# STARTDATE: 1999-01-01 00:00:00

# ALMA_OUTPUT: 0

# NVARS: 10

# YEAR  MONTH   DAY     OUT_SNOW_COVER   OUT_SURF_TEMP   OUT_RUNOFF      OUT_BASEFLOW    OUT_SWE
 OUT_EVAP        OUT_PREC

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 242, in <module>
    main()
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 236, in main
    flux2nc(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 162, in flux2nc
    all_data[:,lat_id,lon_id] = dado
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 731
```

Comment: You need to skip the header. It appears that this is failing on the very first line.

Comment: What if I want to keep the header? and thank you for going through the long code.

Comment: You can keep the header but you need to process it differently than the rows below. You know what you want but the computer does not. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before line 156 you have the for cycle, looping over all the lines:

```
for l in lixo:
```

To print the headers but not evaluate them:

```
for l in lixo:
    if l.startswith('#'):
        print(l)
        continue
```

This solves the runtime error.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but now I am getting the following error:# STARTDATE: 1999-01-01 00:00:00

# ALMA_OUTPUT: 0

# NVARS: 10

# YEAR  MONTH   DAY     OUT_SNOW_COVER   OUT_SURF_TEMP   OUT_RUNOFF      OUT_BASEFLOW    OUT_SWE
 OUT_EVAP        OUT_PREC

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 242, in <module>
    main()
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 236, in main
    flux2nc(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
  File "flux2nc_b.py", line 162, in flux2nc
    all_data[:,lat_id,lon_id] = dado
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 731

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out using the following the code. I had to make some changes.
Thank you everyone for your help.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

#----------------------------------------------------
# Program to convert VIC fluxes files to NetCDF file
# will ask the user which variable he wants to export
# and also for which years. Assumes there is data
# for the entire time period, from 1-jan to 31-dec
# SET UP FOR DAILY TIME STEP. FLUX FILE SHOULD NOT
# CONTAIN HOUR RECORD!!
#----------------------------------------------------

#------------------------------------------------
# Writen by Daniel de Castro Victoria
# dvictori@cena.usp.br or daniel.victoria@gmail.com
# 03-dec-2004
#
# 13-mar-2018: Code update. Change libraries and treat
# header lines. Changes done by Stuart Smith (smit1770 at purdue dot edu)
#-------------------------------------------------

import os
import sys
# handle dates...
import datetime
# SciPy netCDF and NumPy
from scipy.io.netcdf import *
from numpy import *

# In case flux files contains header lines
# set the variable according to the number of lines
skip_lines = 6

# checking user input
print len(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Wrong user input"
    print "Convert VIC fluxes files to NetCDF"
    print "usage flux2cdf.py <vic flux dir>"
    print "VIC FLUX DIR SHOULD CONTAIN TRAILING /"
    sys.exit()

if sys.argv[1][-1] != "/":
    print "VIC FLUX DIR SHOULD CONTAIN TRAILING /"
    print "fixing it for you..."
    sys.argv[1] = sys.argv[1] + "/"

print "IMPORTANT: "+sys.argv[1]+" SHOULD CONTAIN ONLY FLUXES FILES!!!"

# building file list and sorted lat lon list
file_list = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])

lat_t = []
lon_t = []
lat = []
lon = []

for f in file_list:
    lat_t.append(float(f.split("_")[1]))
    lon_t.append(float(f.split("_")[2]))

for i in lat_t:
    if i not in lat:
        lat.append(i)

for i in lon_t:
    if i not in lon:
        lon.append(i)


# putting in order. Lat should be from top to bottom
# lon from left to right
lon.sort()
lat.sort()
lat.reverse()

del(lat_t)
del(lon_t)

#determining the parameter to use
print "Choose output parameter"
print "1 - Snow_Cover"
print "2 - Surface_Temperature"
print "3 - Runoff"
print "4 - Base flow"
print "5 - SWE"
print "6 - Precipitation"
print "7 - Evaporation"
print "8 - Soil Moisture"

varini = input('Choose output (1 a 8)>')

#getting the column right
if int (varini) < 8:
    var = varini + 2
elif varini == 8:        #more than one soil layer...
    camada = input('which soil layer?>')
    var = varini + 1 + camada

#set name of out_file. Named after parameter choice
if var == 3:
    var_txt = "Snow_Cover"
    var_name = "Snow_Cover"
elif var == 4:
    var_txt = "Surf_Temp"
    var_name = "Surface_Temperature"
elif var == 5:
    var_txt = "Runoff"
    var_name = "Runoff"
elif var == 6:
    var_txt = "base"
    var_name = "Baseflow"
elif var == 7:
    var_txt = "SWE"
    var_name = "SWE"
elif var == 8:
    var_txt = "Precipitation"
    var_name = "Precipitation"
elif var == 9:
    var_txt = "Evaporation"
    var_name = "Evaporation"
else:
    var_txt = "soil_"+str(camada)
    var_name = "Soil moisture, layer %i", camada

# for what date?
start_year = input("Enter start year:")
end_year = input("End year:")

inidate = datetime.date(start_year,1,1)
enddate = datetime.date(end_year,12,31)

days = enddate.toordinal() - inidate.toordinal()+1

print "Go grab a coffe, this could take a while..."

#
# create array containing all data
# This is going to be huge. Create an array with -9999 (NoData)
# Then populate the array by reading each flux file
#

all_data = zeros([days,len(lat),len(lon)], float)-9999

c = len(file_list)

# for each file in list
for f in file_list:
    # get lat & lon and it's index
    latitude = float(f.split("_")[1])
    longitude = float(f.split("_")[2])
    lat_id = lat.index(latitude)
    lon_id = lon.index(longitude)

    print "%i files to write." % c
    c = c -1

    infile = open(sys.argv[1]+f, "r")
    # here we skip the number of header lines
    # variable set at the begining of the code
    lixo = infile.readlines()[skip_lines:]
    infile.close()
    dado = []

    for l in lixo:
        if int(l.split("\t")[0]) in range(inidate.year, enddate.year+1):
            dado.append(float(l.split("\t")[var]))
        # putting data inside array.
        # Since data has lat & lon fixed uses dimension [:,lat_index,lon_index]

    all_data[:,lat_id,lon_id] = dado

#
# writing NetCDF
#

ncfile = netcdf_file(var_txt+".nc", "w")

ncfile.Conventions = "COARDS"
ncfile.history = "Created using flux2cdf.py. " + datetime.date.today().isoformat()
ncfile.production = "VIC output"

ncfile.start_date = inidate.isoformat()
ncfile.end_date = enddate.isoformat()

#create dimensions
ncfile.createDimension("X", len(lon))
ncfile.createDimension("Y", len(lat))
ncfile.createDimension("T", days)

#create variables
latvar = ncfile.createVariable("Y", "f4", ("Y",))
latvar.long_name = "Latitude"
latvar.units = "degrees_north"
latvar[:] = lat

lonvar = ncfile.createVariable("X", "f4", ("X",))
lonvar.long_name = "Longitude"
lonvar.units = "degrees_east"
lonvar[:] = lon

timevar = ncfile.createVariable("T", "f4", ("T",))
timevar.long_name = "Time"
timevar.units = "days since " + inidate.isoformat()
timevar[:] = range(0, days)

data_var = ncfile.createVariable(var_txt, "f4", ("T","Y","X"))
data_var.long_name = var_name+" calculated by VIC"
data_var.missing_value = -9999.0
data_var.units = "milimeters"
data_var[:] = all_data

ncfile.close()
```